# How on-topic/off-topic are questions about 'tricks' with (La)Tex editors?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a couple of questions about getting something tricky (well, maybe) done with WinEdt. But the 'Tour' does not make it clear enough how on or off-topic such questions are. Is this kind of question... welcome? Tolerated? Unacceptable? Meh-nobody-cares?

Ok, due to public pressure, I'll be a bit more explicit: Getting WinEdt to automatically find the main file of an article when you haven't set it as the project main file, rather than trying to compile some included section, when you PDFTeXify it by mistake. But **please** do **not** answer this actual question here.

Comment: Maybe you should explain more in detail what you mean by “tricky”, but my understanding is that questions about a (La)TeX suite of different editors are accepted here. I have seen asked and answered many questions about LyX, Emacs, TeXworks etc. as long as they are not about installation problems or random problems the software may give you, but still there are exceptions to that, too. (Personally, my highest upvoted answer is about key bindings in Emacs AUCTeX.)

Comment: @PierPaolo: See edit.

Comment: @cmhughes: So make that an answer maybe?

Answer (score 9):

These sound like very appropriate questions to me :) We have a https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winedt tag that demonstrates your question won't be the first such question :)

---

<sub>PS: I think that [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) might be able to help with your *actual* question.</sub>

Comment: The arara documentation is a clear, beautifully typeset, complete description of the software. Even better, it has a section on "what is arara?", starting from page 29.

Comment: God bless `arara`.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation from the closing and down voting at this site is that all questions regarding *vim* or *emacs* are on topic, questions regarding other editors will normally be treated as off topic :).

Comment: :-) ... but not sure I agree.

Comment: Certainly *not* true. :( However, with compiled applications (like TeXmaker, etc.), it's very hard to actually provide an *answer* other than 'file a bug report'. With something like Emacs, you can reasonably write a function that anyone can stick in their config to fix the problem.

Comment: @SeanAllred - I tried to add a smiley to my answer. Texworks has an advance scripting language and I am pretty sure you can write functions to fix problems in that application to. Notepad++ has a documented interface to plug-ins. I do not see the big differences (but I amneither an emacs user nor a lisp programmer.